# Parsing large text fields

Tags: php, parsing

What is the best function to parse strings between certain characters?

**For example:**

```
CHI 3 - MIN 0

1st
CHI - Kane (Seabrook, Toews)

2nd
CHI - Kane (Seabrook, Toews)

3rd
CHI - Kane (Seabrook, Toews)
```

So this a boxscore of a hockey game, the first name is the goalscorer, and the second two are the assists.

I need to only grab between " - " and " (" for $goalscorer

between " (" and "," for $assist1

add between ", " and ")" for $assist2

**Outcome should be:**

```
$goalscorer = Kane
$assist1 = Seabrook
$assist2 = Toews
```

Ultimately I want to make a big script, where I can paste a bunch of boxscores, and have a loop run through and add "+1" to the players goal/assist columns. But for now, I want to know how to parse the boxscore.

**Greatly appreciate any help!**

Comment: preg_match works great, but maybe a better question is how are you reading the file, file_get_contents? Is the data to be parsed line by line, or do you need to load the whole file, that is what will make a big performance difference.

Comment: I will be likely make a form to paste the boxscore into, and make it into a string. (not sure if that's the smartest thing to do.)

Comment: Is the example the full input you'll be pasting in, or will you only be pasting in the "score lines" (if that's an accurate description) themselves; e.g: `CHI - Kane (Seabrook, Toews)`?

Comment: @Darragh Ideally the full input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here this will match what you have

https://regex101.com/r/yT7aW7/1

```
$str = "CHI - Kane (Seabrook, Toews)";      
preg_match('/^(\w+)\s-\s(?P<goalscorer>\w+)\s\((?P<assist1>\w+),\s(?P<assist2>\w+)\)$/', $str, $matches);
```

In english

- `^` Start of line
- `\w` Any working character includes a-zA-Z_
- `(`\w+`)` capture, `+` more then one
- `\s` A single space
- `-`  a hyphen
- `?P<name>` a named capture group
- `\(` or `\)` literal paren, as oppesed to the capture ones.
- `$` end of line

most of it just repeats those, it's a really basic regular expression.

Comment: Looks good, but how would you modify it for the whole boxscore?

Comment: What's a whole boxscore

Comment: CHI 3 - MIN 0

1st
CHI - Kane (Seabrook, Toews)

2nd
CHI - Kane (Seabrook, Toews)

3rd
CHI - Kane (Seabrook, Toews)

Comment: Um. if your read that line by line, it will only match the lines of that format.

Comment: It will only match the input if it's that format, so if you read the input line by line ( as in a loop )  then you can go `if(preg_match('patt', 'input', $match)` and match will contain your information on the lines that it matches.  Unless there is data in the other lines you want then you probably need to do `}else if( .. second match .. ){`

Comment: Ahh, I get ya now, thanks alot man! I'll fiddle around with the loop! Sorry for being a complete noob, just started learning :)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Comment: +1 for named capture groups, which I never knew existed until now! you learn something new every day. super useful, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that you are asking about two things: 1. How to process the result of your boxscore and filter for relevant lines; 2. extract specific values from those relevant lines.

Assuming your boxscore is a available as a variable called `$str`, you can just explode it on its newlines, iterate over the result, filter for the lines you want and then extract the values from those lines.

Something like this is pretty mechanical but should work, given your example input above:

```
<?php

$str = <<<STR
CHI 3 - MIN 0

1st
CHI - Kane (Seabrook, Toews)

2nd
CHI - Kane (Seabrook, Toews)

3rd
CHI - Kane (Seabrook, Toews)
STR;

// split boxscore input on newlines
// to create an array of lines
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $str);

// iterate over lines
// filter each line... ignore zero-length lines
// check if the last char is ')'
// preg_split on filtered lines
// assign to vars
// etc.
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $len = strlen($line);
    if ($len && $line[$len - 1] === ')') {
        $matches = preg_split('/^\w{3}\s+-\s+|\s+\(|,\s+|\)/', $line, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        list($goalscorer, $assist1, $assist2) = $matches;
        // do whatever you want with `$goalscorer`, `$assist1`, `$assist2`
    }
}
```

Of course, each iteration will overwrite the values of `$goalscorer`, `$assist1` and `$assist2` but I am just illustrating that you can do whatever you want with these values at this point, you can do further operations or write them to an array or something - that seems to be outside the scope of the question for now.

The regex is probably a bit inelegant; it should work for weird double-barrelled and hyphenated surnames.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Such smart people on here! Thanks alot Darragh!

Comment: No problema! That's what we're here for. Glad to help!